# Pulling data from another table while I have the index keys from my table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have three Mysql tables:

```
Brands ( brand names , brand Ids)

cars ( car names,car ids, brand Ids)

statuss ( car Ids, each car status).
```

I am trying to pull the brand names from the brand table but I have the cars IDs. How can I do that see my code below.

---

### Controller.ctp

```
$this->loadModel('car');
        $cars = $this->car>find('all',array('limit' => 6, 'order' => array('car.id' => 'asc')));
        $this->set('cars', $cars);

        $this->loadModel('status');
        $cars = $this->status>find('all',array('limit' => 6, 'order' => array('status.id' => 'asc')));
        $this->set('statuss', $statuss);
```

---

### View.ctp

App::import('Controller', 'cars');
$carsCont = new carsController;

App::import('Controller', 'brands');
$brandCont = new brandsController;

foreach($statuss as $status)

{

$car_info = $carsCont->get_car_info($status['status']['car_id']);

```
            $car_name = $car_info['car_name'];

            $car_id = $status['status']['car_id'];

    $brand_list = $brandCont -> get_brand_name($status['car']['brand_id']); <---- this is not working


  echo $brand_list['brand']['brand']; echo $car_name;
```

}

Comment: Just do a basic subquery, a join would work too. E.g. `SELECT * FROM brandtable WHERE brandid IN (SELECT brandid FROM cartable WHERE carid IN ($carids_seperated_by_comma);` Not too sure how it's formatted within your cakephp project though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP controllers are not designed or meant to be instantiated directly like you are doing.

Rather, you should be making use of the associations that cakephp gives you.

Based on what you've said, you've got Statuses belongsTo Cars belongsTo Brands. Set those relations up in your model files (as documented in the book: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

If you then use the containable behavior (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) you'd be able to do something like (In your status controller)

```
$statuses = $this->Statuses->find('all', [
    'contain' => ['Cars' => 'Brands']
]);
```

and you should have all the data that you need.

Edit: Based on your additions, change your cars query to

```
$cars = $this->car>find('all',array('limit' => 6, 'order' => array('car.id' => 'asc'), 'contain' => ['Brands']));
```

But, make sure Cars BelongsTo Brands, and you've attached the Containable behaviour.

Comment: Dakota, your code brings the statuses. I want the Brand to come out, I know the Car and the Status.

Comment: I've added a bit more, does that help?

Comment: Dakota, I need the $brand_list=  code as I need to show the brands of the cars, so far you showed me how to get the cars and the statuses. Also, Cars table does not have brands names only brands Ids.

Comment: I'm trying to show you how to load in the associated data (i.e. brand name) that you need. My 2nd query will give you exactly what you are looking for, $cars[0]['Brand']['name']